# entity framework "database first" tries to recreate the database

Tags: entity-framework-6, sql-server-2016

I have a ASP.NET MVC website with Entity Framework 6.0 and "database first" approach. Everything was working fine until my web host upgraded to MSSQL Server 2016 SP1. Now the website tries to recreate the database, it seems beacause I'm getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

Nothing else has changed as far as I know. On my dev machine I was able to do the same database upgrade (from 2014 to 2016 SP1) and it still works fine.

I have no migrations-folder and the __MigrationHistory table is empty.

Any suggestions on what to try?

Thanks!

Comment: If it is just an upgrade and the database exists, then check your connection string and make sure you have rights to the database. Can you access the database in SSMS?

Comment: I only have ftp-access to the server but they use an online-version of SSMS and I can access the db there. I also got the latest backup-file (after the upgrade) and after I restored it locally, it worked just fine, so the db seems ok. According to the web host, the connectionstring is also ok. I can't understand why it tries to create the database.

Comment: With certain initializers it tries to create the database when it can't find it. Show your connection string without confidential info.

Comment: I use ASP.NET Identity 2.2 and the line that causes the error is: var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

Comment: The connectionstring is: Data Source=[IP];Initial Catalog=[db-name];Integrated Security=False;User ID=[user];Connect Timeout=300;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096;Password=[password] without the brackets of course

Comment: Does your context inherit from IndentityDbContext or are you using 2 contexts? Since it's a user id/password, you should be able to test that in SSMS.

Comment: Yes, I have an ApplicationDbContext inheriting from IdentityDbContext and using "DefaultConnection" defined in web.config using the connectionstring above. The user works fine when using SSMS and the connectionstring is cut and paste from SSMS.

Comment: If your context is in a separate project, check its app.config for a connection string there. If you are not passing a connect string to constructor of context, you might try that as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Steve! You were right all the way. It was the connection that was failing. I pointed this out for my web host and finally they fixed it so it works.